# Reloading a different page upon a submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am currently making a rota, one of the pages is to update the first and last name on the account that is signed in.

The web page is split up into  a header(Includes to other pages and sign in) body(the content depending on what page you are on) and footer(Holds the current time).

When an account is sign in, they have an option to sign out and it shows the first and last name. When they are signed into the account and change the first or last name and submit, it changes in database, but in order for it to show in the header where it says "You are signed in as Jack Smith" you need to sign out of the account and sign back in.

Im guessing the reason is because each pack always has the header loaded and is not refreshed when the database is updated. I have looked online and I have tried action="window.location.reload()" but doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code for my header and account settings page, along with the database changes. All help is appreciated.

```
HEADER
    <?php
    session_start();
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Egress Lunch Rota</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

<div id="head">
    <table id="span">
        <tr>
            <td id="test">
                <table id="padding2">
                    <tr class="padding">
                            <td class="padding"><a href="index.php">Home</a></td>
                            <td class="padding"><a href="signup.php">Sign up</a></td>
                         <td class="padding"><a href="account.php">Account</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="info">
                <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['first'])) {
                    echo '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Logout</button>
                    </form>';
                } else{ 
                    echo '<form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Log In</button>
                </form>';
                }

                ?>


                    <div id="signup">
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['first']) && isset($_SESSION['last'])) {
                echo "You are signed in as: " . $_SESSION['first']. " ";
                echo $_SESSION['last'];

            } else{
                echo "<br>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>


            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


ACCOUNT HTML PAGE
    </<?php 
    include 'header.php';
 ?>
<body onload="startTime()">

        <div class="accounttitle">
            <b> Change Account Settings</b>
        </div>

    <div class="accountcontent">

            <b>Personal information</b><br>
            <form action="includes/account.inc.php" action="includes/header.inc.php" method="POST">
            <div class="inputs">Firstname:</div> <div class="test"> <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Firstname" class="size"></div>
            <div class="inputs">Secondname:</div> <div class="test">  <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Lastname" class="size"></div>

            <div><button onclick="location.reload()" type="submit" name="submit" class="button">Submit</button></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accountcontent">
        <div>
            <b>Password</b><br>
            <form action="includes/account.inc.php" method="POST">
            <div class="inputs">  Current Password:</div> <div class="test"> <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Current Password" class="size"></div>
            <div class="inputs">  New Password:</div> <div class="test"> <input type="password" name="npassword" placeholder="New Password" class="size"> </div>
            <div class="inputs"> Confirm new Password: </div> <div class="test"> <input type="password" name="cnpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="size"> </div>
            <div><button type="submit" name="submit1" class="button">Submit</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accountcontent">
        <div>
            <b>Security questions</b><br>

            First Security Question:
            <form action="includes/account.inc.php" method="POST">
            <div class="tests">
            <select name="qone">
                <option value="Where did you go for your first holiday?">Where did you go for your first holiday?</option>
                <option value="What make was your first car?">What make was your first car?</option>
                <option value="Where did you spend your honeymoon?">Where did you spend your honeymoon?</option>
                <option value="In what city do you work?">In what city do you work?</option>
                <option value="What is your least favourite job?">What is your least favourite job?</option>
                <option value="What is the name of your first firend?">What is the name of your first friend?</option>
                </select>
                </div>

            First Answer: <div class="tests"> <input type="text" name="aone" placeholder="#1 Answer" class="size"><br> </div>

            Second Security Question:
            <div class="tests">
            <select name="qtwo">
                <option value="Where did you go for your first holiday?">Where did you go for your first holiday?</option>
                <option value="What make was your first car?">What make was your first car?</option>
                <option value="Where did you spend your honeymoon?">Where did you spend your honeymoon?</option>
                <option value="In what city do you work?">In what city do you work?</option>
                <option value="What is your least favourite job?">What is your least favourite job?</option>
                <option value="What is the name of your first firend?">What is the name of your first friend?</option>
                </select>
                </div>


            Second Answer: <div class="tests"> <input type="text" name="atwo" placeholder="#2 Answer" class="size"><br></div>
            <div><button type="submit" name="submit2" class="button">Submit</button></div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>


<?php 
    include 'footer.php';
 ?>


ACCOUNT BACK END
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include_once '../dbh.php';

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);

    //Query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users1";
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM lunch";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

        //Error handlers
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last)){
        header("Location: ../account.php?account=invalid");
        exit();
        }   else{
                        $sql = "UPDATE users1 SET first = '$_POST[first]', last = '$_POST[last]' WHERE id = '$_SESSION[id]'";
                        $sql1 = "UPDATE lunch SET firstname = '$_POST[first]', secondname = '$_POST[last]' WHERE tid = '$_SESSION[id]'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
                        header("Location: ../account.php?account=success");
                        exit();
                        }
}
```

Comment: sounds like you need to update the session variables when user does an edit that is successful

Comment: You maybe right. I was thinking about a Javascript function that does an automatic update every x amount of time but that would include php in a js file which i am sure cannot be done.

Comment: php only runs on server and not in a js file

Comment: Correct so I am unsure on how to do like an automatic update to the header to refresh the change that a user has made.